# How to use cloudflare turnstile captcha with sweetalert2?

Tags: php

I want to check by adding cloudflare turnstile to sweetalert2 notification box.
I am using php.

I've seen material using Google reCaptcha instead of Cloudflare Turnstile. But it was different from the cloudflare turnstile.
Please tell me how!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can see [this page](https://aoimonotw.blogspot.com/2023/11/turnstile-captcha-php.html) to learn how to use cloudflare turnstile with php.

then, with JavaScript(jQuery):

```
.done(function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let captcha = JSON.parse(data.captcha);

  if(!captcha.success){
    let failed_text = captcha['error-codes'].toString();
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'CAPTCHA FAILED',
      text: failed_text,
      icon: 'error'
    });
    turnstile.reset();
  }else{
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'CAPTCHA SUCCESS',
      text: 'some text',
      icon: 'success'
    });
  }
})
```